# Errno: 1452 Constraint

Tags: mysql

When I try to source these tables into MySQL, and it created all the tables. Then I start to populate the tables, and it will not let me populate the last table Rental_Invoice. Any suggestions?

The error is

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`SFRC_HIDDEN`.`Rental_Invoice`, CONSTRAINT
>   `Rental_Invoice_fk_Client_Contact` FOREIGN KEY (`Client_ID`)
>   REFERENCES `Client_Contact` (`Client_ID`))

```
 create table Client_Contact
    (
        Client_ID               int             Primary Key Auto_Increment,
        Client_First_Name       varchar(50)     Not Null,
        Client_Last_Name        varchar(50)     Not Null,
        Client_Address          varchar(50),
        Client_City             varchar(50)     Not Null,
        Client_State            Char(2)         Not Null,
        Client_Zip_Code         varchar(20)     Not Null,
        Client_Phone            varchar(20),
        Client_Email            varchar(30)

    );



    create table Owner_Contact
    (   Owner_ID int Primary Key, 
        Owner_First_Name varchar(50) Not Null,
        Owner_Last_Name varchar(50) Not Null,
        Owner_Address varchar(50), 
        Owner_City varchar(50) Not Null, 
        Owner_State varchar(2) Not Null, 
        Owner_Zip_Code  varchar(20) Not Null, 
        Owner_Phone varchar(20), 
        Owner_Email varchar(30)
        );



    create table Property_Info
    (Property_ID varchar(20) Primary Key,
        Owner_ID int Not Null,
        Property_Type varchar(30) Not Null, 
        Pets set('Yes','No') Not Null, 
        Internet set('yes','No') Not Null, 
         constraint Property_Info_fk_Owner_Contact
             foreign key (Owner_ID)
             references Owner_Contact (Owner_ID));



    create table Rental_Invoice
    ( Invoice_ID int Primary Key, 
      Property_ID varchar(10) Not Null, 
      Client_ID int Not Null, 
      Arrival_Date date Not Null, 
      Departure_Date date Not Null, 
      Deposit_Amount decimal(5,2) Not Null, 
      Pet_Deposit_Amount decimal(7,2), 
      Pet_Type enum('cat', 'dog', ''), 
      Cleaning_Fee decimal(5,2) Not Null, 
      Rental_Rate decimal(5,2) Not Null, 
      Method_Of_Payment varchar(20) Not Null, 
      constraint Rental_Invoice_fk_Client_Contact foreign key (Client_ID) references Client_Contact (Client_ID)
      );
```

Comment: create table Rental_Invoice
( Invoice_ID int Primary Key, 
  Property_ID varchar(10) Not Null, 
  Client_ID int Not Null, 
  Arrival_Date date Not Null, 
  Departure_Date date Not Null, 
  Deposit_Amount decimal(5,2) Not Null, 
  Pet_Deposit_Amount decimal(7,2), 
  Pet_Type enum('cat', 'dog', ''), 
  Cleaning_Fee decimal(5,2) Not Null, 
  Rental_Rate decimal(5,2) Not Null, 
  Method_Of_Payment varchar(20) Not Null, 
  constraint Rental_Invoice_fk_Client_Contact foreign key (Client_ID) references Client_Contact (Client_ID)
  );                         I updated it, but got the error still.

Comment: make   Client_ID  not null as well in your client contact

Comment: "source these tables" - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

**Initial problem**

Just a random guess since I don't have MySQL installed anywhere at the moment. But Client_ID in the dependent table is a VARCHAR and it refers to an INTEGER column in the parent table.

**After Edit**

The foreign key constraint is caused by inserting a row into `Rental_Invoice` that does not have a corresponding row in `Client_Contact`.  In other words, your data violates the `Rental_Invoice_fk_Client_Contact` foreign key constraint that requires that `Rental_Invoice.Client_ID` refers to an existing row in `Client_Contact` with a matching `Client_ID`.